# Extracting text from the middle of a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string that is captured from the DVLA when looking up a car registration details and I need to be able to extract just the numbers from the CC.

> "A5 S LINE BLACK EDITION PLUS TDI 190 (2 DOOR), 1968cc, 2015 -
>   PRESENT"

Given that the lentgh of the string can change, is there a way to do this with a sub-string so for example always grab the numbers from before the cc without the space that comes before it? Bare in mind too that this can sometimes be a 3 digit number or a four digit number.

Comment: Or [5 digits](http://silodrome.com/weineck-cobra-v8/) VROOM!

Comment: You could use a reqular expression to match any sequence of numbers followed by `cc`, eg `\d+cc,` , assuming that `cc,` appears only once in a line. You could even handle any whitespace between `cc` and `,`.  The text needs to follow some pattern though

Comment: So far I haven't tried anything as not sure where to start - @JamesThorpe Lol but I think this site only looks up VW cars ;) - so more than likely only 4

Comment: @JamesThorpe - [Race you](http://car-from-uk.com/sale.php?id=89744)! (or 2 digits)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
string input = "A5 S LINE BLACK EDITION PLUS TDI 190 (2 DOOR), 1968cc, 2015 - PRESENT";
string size;
Regex r = new Regex("(\\d*)cc", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match m = r.Match(input);
if (m.Success) 
{
    size = m.Groups[0];
}
```

It captures every number that is right before `cc`

Comment: Indeed. If the OP knew about regular expressions, the question would be a lot different. Also explain *why* you used the parentheses, and how to extract the value from the Groups using code. Perhaps, even use `(?<cc>\d+)cc` so you can refer to the group by name

Answer (score 4):

If the count of the comma doesn't change you can do following:

```
string s = "A5 S LINE BLACK EDITION PLUS TDI 190 (2 DOOR), 1968cc, 2015 - PRESENT";
string ccString = s.Split(',').ToList().Find(x => x.EndsWith("cc")).Trim();
int cc = Int32.Parse(ccString.Substring(0, ccString.Length - 2));
```

Comment: Simple without regex.

Comment: @WindyHendwiananda not this simple, it will not works with input like `"A5 S LINE BLACK EDITION PLUS TDI 190, (2 DOOR), 1968cc, 2015 - PRESENT"`

Comment: @Thomas now it doesn't matter where the commas are. (updated code)

Comment: Nice one, just be aware of incorrect string like (dummy example) `coccinelle`, that would (try to) parse `co` to an int an raise an exception

Comment: @Thomas Thx, didn't thought about this-> changed `Contains()` to `EndsWith()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```
string text = "A5 S LINE BLACK EDITION PLUS TDI 190 (2 DOOR), 1968cc, 2015 - PRESENT";
string[] substrings = text.Split(',');  
string numeric = new String(substrings[1].Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(numeric);
```

**Here is a working [DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/D3EvQk)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex to match a pattern withing the string - so you can return parts of the string that match the given pattern. This Regex pattern will attempt to match parts of the string that fit the following pattern:

```
\d{1,5} *[cC]{2}
```

- Starts with 1 to 5 digits `\d{1,5}` (seems sensible for an engine cc value!)
- Can then contain 0 or more spaces in between that and cc  `*`
- Ends with any combination of 2 C or c `[cC]{2}`

So you can then use this in the following manner:

```
string str = "A5 S LINE BLACK EDITION PLUS TDI 190 (2 DOOR), 1968cc, 2015 - PRESENT";
Match result = Regex.Match(str, @"\d{1,5} *[cC]{2}");
string cc = result.Value; // 1968cc
```